# What happens when an individual fails to reassert control of a raised or created undead

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, undead, necromancy

When using Animate Dead or Create Undead the person must recast it to reassert control over the creatures or they lose control over them.

But do they just start attacking the creator if they fail to reassert control or do they do nothing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An uncontrolled undead is just a normal, “wild” undead creature, and will act just like any undead you meet during an adventure. Usually that means they will be hostile to you and likely attack, if able.